# ADAL in a loop on the webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, azure, adal

I am creating a website which uses Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries as authentication provider. I followed this tutorial to establish a working situation in my development environment.

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

Everything was working well so far. I am able to authenticate using the tenants users. Because you have to be authenticated for all the pages, I use the [Authorize] attribute for all the controllers. I published the same app to a webserver using different settings in the web.config file. I azure I created 2 applications: 'Apps Test' and 'Apps'.

While the site is now running, multiple users are able log on using their own azure tenant credentials. Now after a while Some users are getting into a loop when they try to log on to the site. The webservers gives the following error in the event log:

> Exception type: OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException
>
> Exception message: IDX10301: The 'nonce' found in the jwt token did
>   not match the expected nonce.

When I restart the application pool and restart the site, the users are able to log on again. For a while...

I have no idea where to look. Do you know what the cause could be?

Comment: Did you ever get a proper solution for this issue? We are expecting the same, even with OpenId Connect 3.0.1, which was supposed to fix the issue.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but adding by 2 cents in. The solution mentioned in the below answer should take care of the nonce issue. However if you are experiencing

Answer (score 1):

We have seen this issue when

1. start a login on one tab
2. when prompted for U / P, open a new tab and browse to the site
3. start a login from the new tab
4. when prompted for U / P, switch back to previous tab
5. complete login on previous tab
6. you should see an error.

There is a suggested fix here:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/wiki/The-'nonce'-found-in-the-jwt-token-did-not-match-the-expected-nonce

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but adding by 2 cents in. The solution proposed by Brent Schmaltz should take care of the nonce issue. However this may also be related to a [bug in the OWIN Middleware](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/197). In short... cookies set by the OWIN middleware sometime disappear. We had resolved this using [Kentor.OwinCookieSaver](https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver).